# error: 'i' does not name a type while compiling with mingw

Tags: c

I am just started C programming and installed minGW. While doing my Hello world test program, I am getting an error as below while compiling my 'test.c' hello world file using - g++ test.c.

> test.c:1:5: error:'i' does not name a type

y_# i n c l u d e

My code -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()

{

printf ("Hello, World!/n")

return 0;

}
```

my path is C:\minGW. I also find stdio.h as installed file - /include/ssp/stdio.h

Can any one tell me what I am missing here.This could help me to start my journey.

Comment: there's no `i` in your code... aside /n should be `\n`

Comment: also g++ is the C++ compiler. You should use gcc instead

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre there are (in include and in int) and it seems the error suggests there is something wrong with the inlcude. But with the code given I would not know what the problem is.

Comment: "here is something wrong with the _inlcude_": yes :)

Comment: You can use Cygwin and GCC in order to run the C code in Windows. Your question title and the problem is misleading.

Comment: `/include/ssp/stdio.h` check the contents of that file. The path is strange for starters

Comment: How is encoded your `test.c` file? The message `y_# i n c l u d e ` let think that it is written in some widechar encoding (UTF-16?)

Comment: Don't use MS Word as your source code editor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message `y_# i n c l u d e` and the double line end suggest that the file `test.c` is encoded in UTF-16 encoding.

Change the file encoding to ascii, it will solve your problem.